# Rust "cannot determine a type for this bounded type parameter: unconstrained type"

Tags: compiler-errors, rust

I just started fiddling with Rust and I found an error I don't understand, trying to build something like a DSL.

I've defined a struct like this:

```
struct Thing<T> {
     a: T
}

impl<T: Show> Thing<T> {
   fn selfie<T>(&self) -> Thing<T> { Thing { a: self.a } }
   fn say<T>(&self) { println!("sing") }
}
```

Then I call it like this and get the error:

```
let a = Thing { a: 1i }; // works
a.say(); // works
let s = a.selfie(); //works
s.say(); // error

main.rs:49:5: 49:12 error: cannot determine a type for this bounded type parameter: unconstrained type
main.rs:49     s.say();
               ^~~~~~~
```

Does anyone know what this error means? I'm having a hard time figuring it out, and have tried a few different casts and nothing seems to work.

Alternatively, is there a better way to return  a reference to "self" (which is what I really wanted to do in the "selfie" method but I was getting errors due to the reference lifespan) or to "an equivalent struct of the same kind"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles with a recent Rust version.

```
use std::fmt::Show;

struct Thing<T> {
     a: T
}

impl<T: Show + Clone> Thing<T> {
   fn selfie(&self) -> Thing<T> { Thing { a: self.a.clone() } }
   fn say(&self) { println!("sing: {}", self.a) }
}
```

I'm assuming that the `say` method should actually print `a` (because otherwise the Show bound makes no sense).

The problem was that in `say<T>` a generic type T exists but cannot be inferred because it's not used. In the selfie method, the `<T>` is not needed. We do need to restrict T to those types that implement Clone though if we want to clone it.

I should also point out that the `selfie` method is reinventing `clone`. You could just do:

```
#[deriving(Clone)]
struct Thing<T> {
     a: T
}
```

and then call `clone()` rather than `selfie`.

Comment: You are right, `say` was supposed to print `a`, I simplified it earlier to rule out the possibility of an error on that `println`. I just tried it and this does indeed work, thanks for the explanation & solution!

Comment: Oh! Regarding deriving `Clone`, I intentionally copied the clone behavior because this is meant to be a DSL, but deriving clone does make it less verbose.